# Perfectly balanced spanning trees

Tags: algorithms, discrete-geometry, trees

I call a spanning tree *perfectly balanced* if, after a two-coloring of the tree-graph's vertices

- the two vertex sets that are defined by the assigned colors have equal cardinality and
- the two vertex sets have equal degree sequence:

[image: example of perfectly balanced spanning tree]

> **Questions:**
>
> - what is the probability that the Minimum Spanning Tree of a set of $2n$ points, that are uniformly distributed in the unit square, is *perfectly balanced*?
> - can *perfectly balanced* spanning trees be calculated efficiently if they exist?

Comment: As a starting point, you might be interested in degree statistics of random MSTs, and one paper that studies those is "On the number of leaves of a Euclidean minimal spanning tree" by Steele, Shepp, and Eddy: https://www.jstor.org/stable/3214207.

Comment: @SamHopkins https://mathoverflow.net/a/301451/31310 has a link to an online article "The random minimal spanning tree in high dimensions"