# Vertex cover via maximally unbalanced spanning trees

Tags: graph-theory, combinatorial-optimization, heuristics

The vertex cover problem asks for a smallest subset $U\subseteq V$ that is adjacent to all edges of a symmetric graph $G(V,E)$.

Inspired by the observation that led to this question [Perfectly balanced spanning trees](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407749/perfectly-balanced-spanning-trees) I asked myself about the properties of maximally unbalanced spanning trees, i.e. trees whose two-coloring of the vertices defines two sets of vertices with maximal difference of cardinality and degree sum.

It seems obvious that the color with fewer vertices in the defined set has higher degree sum and thus provides a more efficient vertex cover than that with fewer vertices.

A highly unbalanced spanning tree can be calculated as the minimum spanning tree if the negative degree-difference of an edge's adjacent vertices serves as the edge-weight.

If the black nodes define the smaller color-set of a spanning tree, then the envisaged heuristic for vertex cover would be to repeat until no uncovered edges remain:

- calculate the maximally unbalanced spanning tree
- add the black nodes to the vertex cover
- remove all covered edges from $E$

> **Questions:**
>
> - is that or a similar heuristic already known?
> - what, if anything, can be said about the quality of the generated vertex covers and/or the approxiation ratio?